# Reproducing a result from R in Stata - Telling R or Stata to remove the same variables causing perfect collinearity/singularities

Tags: r, regression, stata

I am trying to reproduce a result from R in Stata (Please note that the data below is fictitious and serves just as an example). For some reason however, Stata appears to deal with certain issues differently than R. It chooses different dummy variables to kick out in case of multicollinearity.

I have posted a related question dealing with the statistical implications of these country-year dummies being removed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/475694/consequences-for-interpretation-of-coefficients-x-not-defined-because-of-sin).

In the example below, R kicks out 2, while Stata kicks out 3, leading to a different result. Check for example **the coefficients and p-values** for `vote` and `vote_won`.

In essence, all I want to know is how to communicate to either R or Stata, which variables to kick out, so that they both do the same.

## Data

The data looks as follows:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(foreign)
library(censReg)
library(wooldridge)
data('mroz')

year= c(2005, 2010)
country = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")
n <- 2
DT <- data.table(   country = rep(sample(country, length(mroz), replace = T), each = n),
                    year = c(replicate(length(mroz), sample(year, n))))
x <- DT
DT <- rbind(DT, DT); DT <- rbind(DT, DT); DT <- rbind(DT, DT) ; DT <- rbind(DT, DT); DT <- rbind(DT, x)
mroz <- mroz[-c(749:753),]
DT <- cbind(mroz, DT)
DT <- DT %>%
group_by(country) %>%
mutate(base_rate = as.integer(runif(1, 12.5, 37.5))) %>%
group_by(country, year) %>%
mutate(taxrate = base_rate + as.integer(runif(1,-2.5,+2.5)))
DT <- DT %>%
group_by(country, year) %>%
mutate(vote = sample(c(0,1),1), 
votewon = ifelse(vote==1, sample(c(0,1),1),0))
rm(mroz,x, country, year)
```

## The lm regression in R

```
summary(lm(educ ~ exper + I(exper^2) + vote + votewon + country:as.factor(year), data=DT))

Call:
lm(formula = educ ~ exper + I(exper^2) + vote + votewon + country:as.factor(year), 
    data = DT)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-7.450 -0.805 -0.268  0.954  5.332 

Coefficients: (3 not defined because of singularities)
                              Estimate Std. Error t value             Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                  11.170064   0.418578   26.69 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
exper                         0.103880   0.029912    3.47              0.00055 ***
I(exper^2)                   -0.002965   0.000966   -3.07              0.00222 ** 
vote                          0.576865   0.504540    1.14              0.25327    
votewon                       0.622522   0.636241    0.98              0.32818    
countryA:as.factor(year)2005 -0.196348   0.503245   -0.39              0.69653    
countryB:as.factor(year)2005 -0.530681   0.616653   -0.86              0.38975    
countryC:as.factor(year)2005  0.650166   0.552019    1.18              0.23926    
countryD:as.factor(year)2005 -0.515195   0.638060   -0.81              0.41968    
countryE:as.factor(year)2005  0.731681   0.502807    1.46              0.14605    
countryG:as.factor(year)2005  0.213345   0.674642    0.32              0.75192    
countryH:as.factor(year)2005 -0.811374   0.637254   -1.27              0.20334    
countryI:as.factor(year)2005  0.584787   0.503606    1.16              0.24594    
countryJ:as.factor(year)2005  0.554397   0.674789    0.82              0.41158    
countryA:as.factor(year)2010  0.388603   0.503358    0.77              0.44035    
countryB:as.factor(year)2010 -0.727834   0.617210   -1.18              0.23869    
countryC:as.factor(year)2010 -0.308601   0.504041   -0.61              0.54056    
countryD:as.factor(year)2010  0.785603   0.503165    1.56              0.11888    
countryE:as.factor(year)2010  0.280305   0.452293    0.62              0.53562    
countryG:as.factor(year)2010  0.672074   0.674721    1.00              0.31954    
countryH:as.factor(year)2010        NA         NA      NA                   NA    
countryI:as.factor(year)2010        NA         NA      NA                   NA    
countryJ:as.factor(year)2010        NA         NA      NA                   NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.3 on 728 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.037, Adjusted R-squared:  0.0119 
F-statistic: 1.47 on 19 and 728 DF,  p-value: 0.0882
```

## Same regression in Stata

```
write.dta(DT, "C:/Users/.../mroz_adapted.dta")

encode country, gen(n_country)

reg educ c.exper c.exper#c.exper vote votewon n_country#i.year
note: 9.n_country#2010.year omitted because of collinearity
note: 10.n_country#2010.year omitted because of collinearity

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =       748
-------------+----------------------------------   F(21, 726)      =      1.80
       Model |  192.989406        21  9.18997171   Prob > F        =    0.0154
    Residual |  3705.47583       726   5.1039612   R-squared       =    0.0495
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.0220
       Total |  3898.46524       747  5.21882897   Root MSE        =    2.2592

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           educ |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
          exper |   .1109858   .0297829     3.73   0.000      .052515    .1694567
                |
c.exper#c.exper |  -.0031891    .000963    -3.31   0.001    -.0050796   -.0012986
                |
           vote |   .0697273   .4477115     0.16   0.876    -.8092365    .9486911
        votewon |  -.0147825   .6329659    -0.02   0.981    -1.257445    1.227879
                |
 n_country#year |
        A#2010  |   .0858634   .4475956     0.19   0.848    -.7928728    .9645997
        B#2005  |  -.4950677   .5003744    -0.99   0.323    -1.477421    .4872858
        B#2010  |   .0951657   .5010335     0.19   0.849    -.8884818    1.078813
        C#2005  |  -.5162827    .447755    -1.15   0.249    -1.395332    .3627664
        C#2010  |  -.0151834   .4478624    -0.03   0.973    -.8944434    .8640767
        D#2005  |   .3664596   .5008503     0.73   0.465    -.6168283    1.349747
        D#2010  |   .5119858    .500727     1.02   0.307    -.4710599    1.495031
        E#2005  |   .5837942   .6717616     0.87   0.385    -.7350329    1.902621
        E#2010  |    .185601   .5010855     0.37   0.711    -.7981486    1.169351
        F#2005  |   .5987978   .6333009     0.95   0.345    -.6445219    1.842117
        F#2010  |   .4853639   .7763936     0.63   0.532    -1.038881    2.009608
        G#2005  |  -.3341302   .6328998    -0.53   0.598    -1.576663    .9084021
        G#2010  |   .2873193   .6334566     0.45   0.650     -.956306    1.530945
        H#2005  |  -.4365233   .4195984    -1.04   0.299    -1.260294    .3872479
        H#2010  |  -.1683725   .6134262    -0.27   0.784    -1.372673    1.035928
        I#2005  |    -.39264   .7755549    -0.51   0.613    -1.915238    1.129958
        I#2010  |          0  (omitted)
        J#2005  |   1.036108   .4476018     2.31   0.021     .1573591    1.914856
        J#2010  |          0  (omitted)
                |
          _cons |   11.58369    .350721    33.03   0.000     10.89514    12.27224
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: The answer is that you can't and this question has been asked on here before numerous times.

Comment: @rawr Thank you for your comment, but I do not think you are correct. The assumption is no perfect multicollinearity. And the reason for that is that it can not be estimated with perfect multicollinearity present. This assumption is however technically no longer violated after the variables causing perfect multicollinearity are removed. I am not saying that this does not have any consequences (that is also why I posted a question on cross validated/ stackexchange). In any case, even high multicollinearity can be perfectly fine and is not a violation of any assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for your question about which 'variables to kick out": I guess you meant which combination of interaction terms to be used as the reference group for calculating regression coefficients.

By default, Stata uses the combination of the lowest values of two variables as the reference while R uses the highest values of two variables as the reference. I use Stata `auto` data to demonstrate this:

```
# In R 
webuse::webuse("auto")
auto$foreign = as.factor(auto$foreign)
auto$rep78 = as.factor(auto$rep78)
# Model
r_model <- lm(mpg ~ rep78:foreign, data=auto)
broom::tidy(r_model)

# A tibble: 11 x 5
   term            estimate std.error statistic   p.value
   <chr>              <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 (Intercept)        26.3       1.65    15.9    2.09e-23
 2 rep781:foreign0    -5.33      3.88    -1.38   1.74e- 1
 3 rep782:foreign0    -7.21      2.41    -2.99   4.01e- 3
 4 rep783:foreign0    -7.33      1.91    -3.84   2.94e- 4
 5 rep784:foreign0    -7.89      2.34    -3.37   1.29e- 3
 6 rep785:foreign0     5.67      3.88     1.46   1.49e- 1
 7 rep781:foreign1    NA        NA       NA     NA       
 8 rep782:foreign1    NA        NA       NA     NA       
 9 rep783:foreign1    -3.00      3.31    -0.907  3.68e- 1
10 rep784:foreign1    -1.44      2.34    -0.618  5.39e- 1
11 rep785:foreign1    NA        NA       NA     NA
```

In Stata:

```
. reg mpg i.foreign#i.rep78
note: 1.foreign#1b.rep78 identifies no observations in the sample
note: 1.foreign#2.rep78 identifies no observations in the sample

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        69
-------------+----------------------------------   F(7, 61)        =      4.88
       Model |  839.550121         7  119.935732   Prob > F        =    0.0002
    Residual |  1500.65278        61  24.6008652   R-squared       =    0.3588
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.2852
       Total |   2340.2029        68  34.4147485   Root MSE        =    4.9599

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          mpg |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
foreign#rep78 |
  Domestic#2  |     -1.875   3.921166    -0.48   0.634    -9.715855    5.965855
  Domestic#3  |         -2   3.634773    -0.55   0.584    -9.268178    5.268178
  Domestic#4  |  -2.555556   3.877352    -0.66   0.512     -10.3088     5.19769
  Domestic#5  |         11   4.959926     2.22   0.030     1.082015    20.91798
   Foreign#1  |          0  (empty)
   Foreign#2  |          0  (empty)
   Foreign#3  |   2.333333   4.527772     0.52   0.608    -6.720507    11.38717
   Foreign#4  |   3.888889   3.877352     1.00   0.320    -3.864357    11.64213
   Foreign#5  |   5.333333   3.877352     1.38   0.174    -2.419912    13.08658
              |
        _cons |         21   3.507197     5.99   0.000     13.98693    28.01307
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

To reproduce the previous `R` in `Stata`, we could recode those two variables `foreign` and `rep78`:

```
. reg mpg i.foreign2#i.rep2
note: 0b.foreign2#1.rep2 identifies no observations in the sample
note: 0b.foreign2#2.rep2 identifies no observations in the sample

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        69
-------------+----------------------------------   F(7, 61)        =      4.88
       Model |  839.550121         7  119.935732   Prob > F        =    0.0002
    Residual |  1500.65278        61  24.6008652   R-squared       =    0.3588
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.2852
       Total |   2340.2029        68  34.4147485   Root MSE        =    4.9599

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          mpg |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
foreign2#rep2 |
         0 1  |          0  (empty)
         0 2  |          0  (empty)
         0 3  |         -3   3.306617    -0.91   0.368     -9.61199     3.61199
         0 4  |  -1.444444   2.338132    -0.62   0.539    -6.119827    3.230938
         1 0  |   5.666667   3.877352     1.46   0.149    -2.086579    13.41991
         1 1  |  -5.333333   3.877352    -1.38   0.174    -13.08658    2.419912
         1 2  |  -7.208333   2.410091    -2.99   0.004    -12.02761   -2.389059
         1 3  |  -7.333333   1.909076    -3.84   0.000    -11.15077   -3.515899
         1 4  |  -7.888889   2.338132    -3.37   0.001    -12.56427   -3.213506
              |
        _cons |   26.33333   1.653309    15.93   0.000     23.02734    29.63933
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The same approach applies to reproduce `Stata` results in `R`, just redefine `levels` of those two factor variables.